# Using the integral test for convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

The question asks if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\log{n})^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges. They then proceed to use the integral test for convergence of the series (they being Serge Lang undergraduate analysis) using the bounds of the integral from $2$ to infinity.

But one of the criterion for using the integral test is that the function must be defined for all $x\geq 1$ however this function is clearly not defined at $x=1$ since $\ln(1) = 0$. Unless they are using $\log$ to not be the natural logarithm, in any case why is the lower limit of the integral $2$ and $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), the problem boils down to proving that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}} $$
is convergent for any $\varepsilon>0$.

However, the original series should start at $n=2$, otherwise the very first term is undefined.